# Coldfusion SQL Query Select and Update in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion

Stuck with the following problem. I want to do a SQL SELECT and UPDATE in one query. This I got working, but I'm not getting the results.

Here's my example code:

```
<cfquery name="GetListings" datasource="#application.dsn#"  result="get_data">

UPDATE listings AS t, 

(
            SELECT *
            FROM listings 
            WHERE group = 92
) AS temp

SET t.premium_listing_count = t.premium_listing_count + 1 WHERE temp.id = t.id

</cfquery>
```

The field premium_listings_count is incremented as it should.

But when I want to simply output the SELECT query with the following:

```
<cfoutput query="GetListings">
#id#
</cfoutput>
```

I get no results, actually it doesn't even know the variable 'GetListings'

Any ideas?

Comment: This query doesn't make any sense... What are you expecting to get as a result here?

Comment: What I'm try to achieve is the result from SELECT * FROM listings WHERE group = 92 and then that all records with group = 92 the field premium_listing_count is Incremented by 1.

Comment: You say, `I want to do a SQL SELECT and UPDATE in one query`.  You can't.  Think of another approach.

Answer (score 0):

You only have an `UPDATE` query here, not a `SELECT` as well. The `SELECT` statement in the query is seen as making another table which is joined with `t` with the comma you use. The `UPDATE` is then run on this joined table, but since you are joining `listings` with a refined version of `listings` you are essentially just updating `listings`, which is why your `UPDATE` is working. You shouldn't be receiving any data back though since `UPDATE` only modifies rows, not return data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which database server you're using. This is certainly possible in MS SQL Server. In fact, you can execute what amounts to a T-SQL program with variables and conditional logic inside a cfquery tag when using MS SQL Server.

However, the only data you can retrieve from all of the SQL that gets executed is a single result set. If you want multiple result sets or to pass other values back out you'll have to use cfstoredproc.

The following code will accomplish what you want if you're using MS SQL Server. I'm sure your database can do something similar.

```
<cfquery name="GetListings" datasource="#application.dsn#" result="get_data">
    SELECT * FROM listings WHERE [group] = 92;

    UPDATE listings
    SET
        premium_listing_count = premium_listing_count + 1
    WHERE
        [group] = 92;
</cfquery>
```

If fact, you can do this with a single statement in MS SQL Server. E.g.,

```
<cfquery name="GetListings" datasource="#application.dsn#" result="get_data">
    UPDATE listings
    SET
        premium_listing_count = premium_listing_count + 1
    OUTPUT
        deleted.*
    WHERE
        [group] = 92;
</cfquery>
```

Group has to be enclosed in brackets in the queries because it's a reserved word in SQL Server.

Edit:

Once I realized you were specifically asking about MYSQL, this is the answer to your question -

Yes, you can include multiple queries by adding "allowMultiQueries=true" to the connection string in the CF datasource. However, everything else I mentioned above still applies. You just have to use MYSQL syntax.